# Unable to load Bootstrap Progress Bar Using AJAX with webpy

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, web.py

I am running a webpy web application with a template HTML file containing a  Bootstrap progress bar. I want to use jQuery AJAX to update the progress bar with values from the server.

I used setInterval() to make GET requests every second and increment a variable on the server, currentProgress, with a random value with each GET. I pass the currentProgress value into the index.html template variable $percentLoaded.

**PROBLEM:** When I run the web page, the value on the server (currentProgress) does update which I can see when I print it to the command prompt. However, the value of $percentLoaded does not update until I refresh the browser, as shown by console.log($percentLoaded).

**The result is that the web page will not update without re-loading it. How can I make it so that AJAX will update $percentLoaded so that the progress bar updates without me having to refresh the page?**

Note: The eventual goal is to retrieve meaningful values from the server but I am using the "dummy" function getProgressIncrement() as a proxy to get the basics working.

**app.py**

```
import web
import random

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

render = web.template.render('templates/')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

currentProgress = 0

def getProgressIncrement():
    global currentProgress
    currentVal = currentProgress
    remainingProgress = 100 - currentVal
    if currentVal == 100:
        return 0
    elif remainingProgress <= 5:
        return remainingProgress
    else:
        return random.randint(1, 6)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        global currentProgress
        # print currentProgress
        currentProgress += getProgressIncrement()
        return render.index(currentProgress)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**templates/index.html**

```html
$def with (percentLoaded)

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="progress" id="outerBar">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%"
        id="myBar">
        0%
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // much of this code is from http://elfga.com/articles/bootstrap-progress-bar-update-jqueryajax/
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var progressPump = setInterval(function () {
            /* query the completion percentage from the server */
            jQuery.get("/", function () {
                // console.log($percentLoaded);
                /* update the progress bar width */
                jQuery("#myBar").css('width', $percentLoaded + '%');
                /* and display the numeric value */
                jQuery("#myBar").html($percentLoaded + '%');

                /* test to see if the job has completed */
                if ($percentLoaded > 99.999) {
                    clearInterval(progressPump);
                    jQuery("#outerBar").removeClass("active");
                    jQuery("#myBar").html("Done");
                }
            })
        }, 1000);
    });

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out after reading the vanilla AJAX tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) followed by the jQuery AJAX tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp) and realizing that I need an extra Python class to return the updated server value instead of relying on WebPy's templating. Here's the updated code:

**app.py**

```
import web
import random

urls = (
    '/', 'index',
    '/updateProgress', 'updateProgress'
)

render = web.template.render('templates/')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

currentProgress = 0

def getProgressIncrement():
    global currentProgress
    currentVal = currentProgress
    remainingProgress = 100 - currentVal
    if currentVal == 100:
        return 0
    elif remainingProgress <= 5:
        return remainingProgress
    else:
        return random.randint(1, 6)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return render.index()

class updateProgress:
    def GET(self):
        global currentProgress
        currentProgress += getProgressIncrement()
        return str(currentProgress)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**templates/index.html**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="progress" id="outerBar">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%"
        id="myBar">
        0%
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var progressPump = setInterval(function() {
            jQuery("#myBar").load("/updateProgress", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xmlReqObj) {
                if (statusTxt == 'success') {
                    jQuery("#myBar").css('width', responseTxt + '%');
                    jQuery("#myBar").html(responseTxt + '%');
                }
                if (statusTxt == 'error') {
                    alert("Error: " + xmlReqObj.status + ": " + xmlReqObj.statusTxt);
                    clearInterval(progressPump);
                }
                if (responseTxt == '100') {
                    clearInterval(progressPump);
                    jQuery("#outerBar").removeClass("active");
                    jQuery("#myBar").html("Done");
                }
            });
        }, 500);
    });
    
</script>

</html>
```